add multiple recipients to sendgrid
i am unable to send mail to multiple receipents with code as below.
adding 3  or more mail ids to 'to_emails'
to = 'aaa@mail.com,bbb@mail.com,ccc@mail.com'
html_content1 = ''' Sample'''
message = Mail(
from_email='from@mail.com',
       to_emails=to,
       subject=fl,
       html_content=html_content1)
with open('attachment', 'rb') as f:
     data = f.read()
     f.close()
 encoded = base64.b64encode(data).decode()
 attachment = Attachment()
 attachment.file_content = FileContent(encoded)
 attachment.file_type = FileType('application/pdf')
 attachment.file_name = FileName(file+'.pdf')
 attachment.disposition = Disposition('attachment')
 attachment.content_id = ContentId('Example Content ID')
 message.attachment = attachment
 sendgrid_client = SendGridAPIClient('key')
 response = sendgrid_client.send(message)
 print(response.status_code)
 print(response.body)
 print(response.headers)

Any modifications required in above code.
Thanks in advance.

It appears that you are attempting to send an email to numerous recipients, however the way you have formatted the to_emails parameter does not meet SendGrid's API standards. You must give the email addresses as a list of strings or a list of To objects from the SendGrid library.
Here's how you can modify your code:

Generate a list of recipient email addresses. You may use either the email strings or the To object to specify extra parameters such as the recipient's name.
# List of email strings
to_emails = ['aaa@mail.com', 'bbb@mail.com', 'ccc@mail.com']

# OR

# List of To objects with optional names
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import To
to_emails = [
    To(email='aaa@mail.com', name='Person One'),
    To(email='bbb@mail.com', name='Person Two'),
    To(email='ccc@mail.com', name='Person Three')
]


Add these to your Mail object setup. Here's the revised code snippet:
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail, Attachment, FileContent, FileName, FileType, Disposition, ContentId
import base64

# Define the recipients
to_emails = ['aaa@mail.com', 'bbb@mail.com', 'ccc@mail.com']

# Email content
html_content = "Sample"
subject = "Your Subject Here"
from_email = 'from@mail.com'

# Create the mail object
message = Mail(
    from_email=from_email,
    to_emails=to_emails,
    subject=subject,
    html_content=html_content
)

# Read and encode the attachment
with open('attachment', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
encoded = base64.b64encode(data).decode()

# Set up the attachment
attachment = Attachment()
attachment.file_content = FileContent(encoded)
attachment.file_type = FileType('application/pdf')
attachment.file_name = FileName('file.pdf')
attachment.disposition = Disposition('attachment')
attachment.content_id = ContentId('Example Content ID')
message.attachment = attachment

# Send the email
sendgrid_client = SendGridAPIClient('your_sendgrid_api_key')
response = sendgrid_client.send(message)

# Print response details
print(response.status_code)
print(response.body)
print(response.headers)



Make sure to substitute your_sendgrid_api_key with your SendGrid API key. This solution guarantees that you have appropriately configured the to_emails option and should remedy the issue you're having with numerous recipients.

Thanks, if i am doing like to_emails = to.split(',')  and then message = Mail(
from_email=from_email,
to_emails=to_emails,
subject=subject,
html_content=html_content
)

throws a bad 400 error
